# ActionBar ignoring splitActionBarWhenNarrow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I found a guide explaining how to do a split action bar [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#SplitBar).

As far as I can tell, this is implemented. But, nothing happens. I've tried running the smallest possible devices in the emulator, and my own Galaxy Nexus. No effect.

Ideas why? How do I go about finding out why this doesn't work? It's not like I'm getting any error messages.

XML:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.tt.activity.ProjectActivity"
        uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: try with removing    uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"

Answer (score -1):

Try this to Dun your work:-

```
     android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" 
     >
```

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```